# Dual Booting Ubuntu / Windows 10 - WiFi on Ubuntu is extremely slow

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, iwlwifi

For the past 2 days I've been struggling with trying to get a decent connection and speed of my WiFi. The Wireless speed on the Windows OS runs perfectly fine.

I've created a dual-boot on my laptop just to try Ubuntu and get the feel of it since I'm losing the feel for Windows now. However, after I installed Ubuntu I found out that my WiFi speed is REALLY slow.

I checked different posts what might be causing this but couldn't come to a solution of my problem.

Wireless Info: https://paste.ubuntu.com/25158086/

Dmesg: https://paste.ubuntu.com/25158097/

Comment: Try this - https://dfspspirit.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/wifi-connection-slow-and-unstable-on-intel-wireless-7260-and-linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://dfspspirit.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/wifi-connection-slow-and-unstable-on-intel-wireless-7260-and-linux/

> The solution is the usual way of passing options to drivers in linux,
>   you edit the config file and add the option you want. The driver for
>   the Intel 7260 is called iwlwifi, and the config file is at
>   /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf under debian-based distros.
>
> To disable 11n, append the following line to that file:
>
> options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
>
> Then reboot your laptop, and you should have way better wifi.

Comment: This is not a good idea with 7260.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Can you explain why not and/or offer a better solution ? So unlike you to leave such a cryptic comment.

Comment: Well. I am using the 7260 and know it quite well. The `11n_dsable` solutions are good for older Intel adapters. Disabling 802.11n won't definitely make it faster ;-)

Comment: According to the OP - "This worked perfectly fine! Thank you!" so transcribed the WP blog here. I dont have the chip to test.

Comment: I can suggest to change the wireless channel form 10 to 1. There are strong APs at 10 and 11.

Comment: It could work fine with a slower rate. At least better than it was. But it doesn't look like a good solution anyway.